# Create regular sequence of a certain length, between two limits

Tags: r, sequence

I am trying to generate python numpy's linspace function's kind of functionality in R. I want to generate equally spaced numbers between a start and an end value, with *given length* of the sequence.

For example between 10 and 100 if I want to use generate 3 equally spaced numbers. the python code for that would be

```
linspace(from = 10, to = 100, n = 3)
```

the output would be : 10 55 100, with difference 45 between each subsequent values.

Any idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: `seq(0, 1, length.out = 11)`, the first example in `?seq`.

Comment: @JasonWang  : Would seq programmatically generate equally spaced values between two limits. Can you give me an example for the 10 to 100 part?

Comment: Try `seq(10, 100, length.out=3)`.

Comment: @JasonWang worked like a charm!

Answer (score 8):

As suggested by JasonWang, the solution is to use the `length.out` argument.

```
seq(from = 0, to = 1, length.out = 11)
```

produces 11 equally spaced values between 0 and 1.

See `?seq` for help which will have an explanation of how to use the `seq` function.

Comment: You may want to give credit to the person that gave you the answer.